# Как получить одну строчку в PDO

Tags: php, pdo

при выполнении запроса на sql-сервере я получаю лишь одну строчку, но используя следующий код получается массив елементом которого явлется другой массив в котором уже строчка:

```
public static function getUsersByID($id)
    {
        $db = Db::getConnectionD();
        $userList = array();

        $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM dbo.Users WHERE IDU = ' . $id . ' ORDER BY Fam');
        $i = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $userList[$i]['IDU'] = $row['IDU'];
            $userList[$i]['Fam'] = $row['Fam'];
            $userList[$i]['Io'] = $row['Io'];
            $userList[$i]['Dolzh'] = $row['Dolzh'];
            $userList[$i]['PsUser'] = $row['PsUser'];

            $i++;
        }
```

вот такой вывод получаю

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [IDU] => 451
            [Fam] => Авакян
            [Io] => Карина Ванушевна
            [Dolzh] => Инженер МИППС
            [PsUser] => Gfotyrj141
        )

)
```

как сделать чтобы получал только :

```
Array
            (
                [IDU] => 451
                [Fam] => Авакян
                [Io] => Карина Ванушевна
                [Dolzh] => Инженер МИППС
                [PsUser] => Gfotyrj141
            )
```

Comment: сделать `return $result->fetch()` видимо. и почитать про передачу параметров в запросы

Comment: в `$result->fetch()` у вас уже тот массив, который вам нужен. Вы его зачем-то перекладываете в другой и спрашиваете, как сделать из него исходный.

Comment: причем это перекладывание в другой, даже если бы и было нужно (если запрос возвращает несклько строк), **тоже делается не так**, без всего этого бессмысленного переливания из пустого в порожнее, `'IDU' ='IDU'`. **Одной** строчкой `$userListp[] = $row` внутри цикла. И это если не знать про функцию PDO, которая все это умеет делать сама

Comment: @Ипатьев это ж надо еще потрудиться `select *` переписать с указанием полей.